# Can I use douglas fir to make cutting boards and how thick should I make them?

Tags: wood

Can I use the other surgery cutting boards and how big should I make them?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "surgery cutting board". Yes you can make cutting boards from doug fir, but how thick to make them is pretty much up to you. Any reasonable thickness should be fine as boards of a wide range of thicknesses are already made. What style of construction were you thinking of, end-grain blocks (true butcher block) or a long-grain slab?

Comment: I made a end grain cutting board out of Douglas Fir about 8 years ago and we used it almost everyday, I've only oiled it twice and its holding up great. It is about 2 inches thick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Douglas fir makes *fantastic* end-grain cutting boards with dramatic swirls. The thickness is really a personal preference depending on the finished size of the board. I would suggest making a 20x12 board 2" thick. I wouldn't suggest ever making an end-grain cutting board less than 1" thick.

I do have a few suggestions if you're talking about using construction-grade lumber from the big-box store:

1. Get 2x10s or 2x12s instead of 2x4s. These have far fewer defects and will make a nicer looking end piece.
2. Dry the wood out in your oven at 215°F for 2-3 hours before you really start working with it. This will prevent the wood from possibly splitting at some future point.

Comment: Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Comment: the temperate is in fahrenheit